# Earth Engine FeatureCollection to Image

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I am quite new to EE. Currently, I am trying to 'burn' polygons from a feature collection to an image. I tried a few references ([link1](https://github.com/giswqs/qgis-earthengine-examples/blob/master/FeatureCollection/reduce_to_image.py), [link2](https://github.com/giswqs/qgis-earthengine-examples/blob/master/FeatureCollection/reducing_feature_collection.py)), but I haven't been able to use them effectively for the scope I am about.

I tried:

```
dataset = ee.FeatureCollection("WCMC/WDPA/current/polygons") \
    .filterBounds(ee.Geometry.Rectangle(*bbox)) # [xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax] 

# Option 1
image = ee.Image().float().paint(dataset, "REP_AREA")

# Option 2
image = dataset.reduceToImage(["REP_AREA"], "mean")
```

But the output is a GeoTif cropped on the bounding box, with all pixels having the same value. I exported it with geemap:

```
geemap.ee_export_image(image, 'protected_areas.tif', region=boundary) # ee.Geometry.LineString
```

If I use the inspector directly into EE's code editor, I clearly see that the polygons are there with the property I'd expect. What am I doing wrong?